# VoiceOver: how to implement button that behaves like keys in Calculator

Tags: ios, uibutton, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When you focus on a digit key in the Calculator app when using VoiceOver (either by tapping it once, sliding a finger over it, or by swiping left/right to it), VoiceOver announces the button title. Then if you "activate" the button by double tapping, it presses the button and VoiceOver announces the character that was inserted into the Calculator display with a higher pitch than the button title announcement.

My question is: how can I get the same behavior for buttons in my app - repeat the button title in a higher pitch upon activating the button?

I've set the accessibility traits to Keyboard Key. I've tried to post an announcement notification but that announcement is not in a higher pitch.

Comment: Are you also setting the accessibility label?

Comment: @unobf No, I let VoiceOver announce the button's title text.

Comment: Try setting the accessibility label

Comment: @unobf Setting `accessibilityLabel` didn't change the behavior - it just announces that label once.

Answer (score 0):

Override the accessibilityActivate method to perform certain actions when the user has invoked the action of your control.

Comment: Ok, then what? You can use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` but doing so results in VoiceOver announcing things over top of it, for example if you post `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification`.